# How do i rectify the error raised due to memory allocation in c++?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, vtk, itk

I am working with ITK and am trying to run the code from the link [3DdeformableRegistration.cxx](https://itk.org/Doxygen45/html/Registration_2DeformableRegistration7_8cxx-example.html) in visual studio. The following error is shown up when executing the "Registration->update()" line.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/340EZ.png)

Comment: Um, you debug your program? It looks like you're trying to load 29 million images and ran out of memory. Only you know whether 29 million images is what you intended.

Comment: and we hope you don't `resize` the vector for every new image.

Comment: That's number of pixels used for evaluating the metric.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a smaller input image. Or try closing some programs when you run this example. If that is not enough, try [increasing size of the virtual memory](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20increase%20virtual%20memory).